# How to change formatting options based on solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ide

My boss set our IDEs up to use non-standard formatting. For example, it adds spaces between the parenthesis and parameters. This is fine for the new stuff that we've started from scratch, but it's super annoying when I go into existing projects and try to format the code with Ctrl-k-d because when I go to compare the file with the latest version before checking in my changes it looks like I've changed almost every single line in the file and it's difficult to pick out the actual changes.

I would like to be able to use his settings in the newer development, but switch to the default settings when working with other projects. Is there a way to accomplish this without having to go into the settings and uncheck/recheck all the appropriate options every time?

EDIT: I understand it might be good to reformat all legacy code to use the new standards. Unfortunately, that's not my decision to make. And even so, I sometimes work from my personal computer which I also use on occasion to do contract work for other companies. I obviously can't reformat their code to fit my bosses standards.

Comment: Seems to me, you have a coding standard set.  Why would you want to change that coding standard just because you are in a legacy project?

Comment: The price you pay for changing coding standards is at least one horrendous check in. I would open the solution, apply the new formatting to all the files, recompile, run tests and check in. I.e. make all the changes to formatting only to re-baseline the solution. Then edit and check in on top of that to give traceability of newer changes. Hopefully a few months from now the ugly blip in your code to get to the new format is long forgotten. Personally I stick to the Visual Studio defaults for portability.

Comment: @paqogomez Because the legacy product was written with a different coding standard. Unless there's a super simple way for me to reformat every code file in the legacy project (which I would suggest is not a good idea anyway), then I would prefer to stick with the standard that was set for the solution I'm working in.

Comment: Gotta go with @MurrayFoxcroft on this one.  Yes, its painful, but rip the bandaid off and just reformat.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I up voted your comment because I agree with your sentiments, but see my edit.

Comment: @BVernon, I think you cover two interesting angles there. If the code is a "PRODUCT", living and evolving, then I would do the migration to the new format. If it is a limited term "SOLUTION", then leave as is. One trick may be to create a second account on your local machine and have another user set up without the newfangled standards. Then you could switch as needed.

Comment: Hmm... isn't there a way to take the formatting options that I'm using and export them into a file that I can import from another machine?

Comment: you might look into stylecop or a formatting tool.  stylecop's settings can be imported and i believe that you switch profiles.

Comment: If your settings are being applied somewhere in Studio, you can work with them as per this article: http://community.submain.com/blogs/howto/archive/2009/05/30/how-to-backup-and-restore-visual-studio-settings.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rebracer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/410e9b9f-65f3-4495-b68e-15567e543c58) extension stores code formatting options alongside each solution and when you open a solution, Rebracer will automatically apply that solution's settings.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* easily switch between settings, by creating separate `.settings` files and using a VSIX package to switch between them by loading them into Visual Studio - I use this for switching between Dual and Single monitor settings via menu items in the Tools menu.

Using an extension is annoyingly complex for such a simple operation, and this was a whole lot easier when Visual Studio supported macros. However I've [uploaded my homebrew extension to GitHub](https://github.com/stuartd/SwitchSettings/tree/master) in case you want to have a look.

The tricky bit is editing the settings files to only contain the ones you're interested in, which I expect are the ones in `Text Editor\C#\Formatting\Spacing`.

Comment: Those are indeed the ones. Thanks.